# MediaPlayer.prepare() THROWS illegeal state exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to stream a Video in android. For one uri it works fine if i go to another it throws illegalstateexception. Actually my code is

```
public class VideoSample extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, Callback,         OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    OnClickListener, OnSeekCompleteListener, AnimationListener {
private TextView textViewPlayed;
private TextView textViewLength;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
private SurfaceView surfaceViewFrame;
private ImageView imageViewPauseIndicator;
private MediaPlayer player;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private ProgressBar progressBarWait;
private Timer updateTimer;
private Bundle extras;
private Animation hideMediaController;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutMediaController;
private static final String TAG = "androidEx2 = VideoSample";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videosample);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    linearLayoutMediaController = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMediaController);
    linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    hideMediaController = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.disapearing);
    hideMediaController.setAnimationListener(this);

    imageViewPauseIndicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPauseIndicator);
    imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (player != null) {
        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
            imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    textViewPlayed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPlayed);
    textViewLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLength);

    surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
    surfaceViewFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(false);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarProgress);
    seekBarProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);

    progressBarWait = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarWait);

    holder = surfaceViewFrame.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

}

private void playVideo() {
    if (extras.getString("video_path").equals("VIDEO_URI")) {
        showToast("Please, set the video URI in HelloAndroidActivity.java in onClick(View v) method");
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(extras.getString("video_path"));
                    Log.i(TAG, extras.getString("video_path"));
                    player.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video Argument");
                    Log.i(TAG, "========== IllegalArgumentException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video State");
                    Log.i(TAG, "========== IllegalStateException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video. Please, check your network connection.");
                    Log.i(TAG, "========== IOException ===========");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

private void showToast(final String string) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoSample.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void hideMediaController() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        linearLayoutMediaController.startAnimation(hideMediaController);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    Log.i(TAG, "========== onProgressChanged : " + progress + " from user: " + fromUser);
    if (!fromUser) {
        textViewPlayed.setText(Utils.durationInSecondsToString(progress));
    }
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress() * 1000);
        Log.i(TAG, "========== SeekTo : " + seekBar.getProgress());
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    playVideo();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "========== onPrepared ===========");
    int duration = mp.getDuration() / 1000; // duration in seconds
    seekBarProgress.setMax(duration);
    textViewLength.setText(Utils.durationInSecondsToString(duration));
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Get the dimensions of the video
    int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;
    Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + videoWidth + " H: " + videoHeight + " PROP: " + videoProportion);

    // Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
    Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + screenWidth + " H: " + screenHeight + " PROP: " + screenProportion);

    // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }

    // Commit the layout parameters
    surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

    // Start video
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.start();
        updateMediaProgress();
        linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hideMediaController();
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(true);
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.stop();
    if (updateTimer != null) {
        updateTimer.cancel();
    }
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    player.release();
}

/**
 * Change progress of mediaController
 * */
private void updateMediaProgress() {
    updateTimer = new Timer("progress Updater");
    updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    seekBarProgress.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    int progress = (int) ((float) mp.getDuration() * ((float) percent / (float) 100));
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(progress / 1000);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.surfaceViewFrame) {
        if (linearLayoutMediaController.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hideMediaController();
        } else if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();
                imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                player.start();
                imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

This is the working uri http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp

This one throws illegalstateexception at mp.prepare() http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4

Comment: _"This one throws illegalstateexception at mp.prepare()"_ Then your question should include the exception stacktrace from the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stream video on android devices, you can use VideoView class.
The VideoView class can load images from various sources, takes care of computing its measurement from the video so that it can be used in any layout manager, and provides various display options such as scaling and tinting.

i've tried the video that gave you an error and it worked well.
You will find below the code that I've used to test your link for streaming the video:

```
VideoView videoview;
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
try {
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoViewerActivity.this);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4");
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    videoview.setVideoURI(video);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
```

And don't forget to put the videoView in your .xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have any question related to my answer, do not hesitate to contact me.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting illegal state exception for player.prepare(), you can **try restarting MediaPlayer object in respective catch block** like in below code snippet. (Also its better to call start() only after mediaPlayer is prepared):

```
try{
    player.prepare();
}catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource(extras.getString("video_path"));
    Log.i(TAG, extras.getString("video_path"));
    player.prepare();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
       mp.start();
       }
    });
}
```